# Excel showing weird tag

Tags: excel

[image]

I am using Excel in MAC for awhile. These grey tag keep coming out , is there any way to disable it ?
Thank You

Comment: Do they disappear if you switch to another sheet and then switch back?

Comment: They dont dissapear , in fact if i don't minimize the excel , it will continue to appear on top of my other stuff.

Comment: Does it only occur when the selected range is outside of the visible range?

Comment: I don't know why it's happening, but those tags are telling you how many rows and columns are selected. Maybe you're having video card issues?

Comment: @JohnColeman no idea how does it occur. It came out of the sudden when i use excel.

Comment: @DougGlancy any pointer how can i test is it video card issues ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no I don't.